# How to parse to String from JSpinner?

Tags: string, jspinner

I was trying to get a String from a JSpinner's input.

How could I parse the input to String?

I tried:

```
  JSpinner jSpinner = (JSpinner) e.getSource();
  dates = (Date) jSpinner.getValue();
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy");
  ta2.setText(df.parse((String)jSpinner.getValue()));
  // or this, which works but it throws an exception because of date.
  ta2.setText((String)jSpinner.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

It was somehow simple now it works.

I added:

```
String nt = df.format(dates);
```